# Connecting Sensor tag with Raspberry pi issue

Tags: raspberry-pi

When I'm trying to run the sensortag.js it is not connecting to the mqtt protocol and it is throwing an error like ----

**Device MAC Address: b827eba64d35
Make sure the Sensor Tag is on!
client errorError: Connection refused: Not authorized**

Can anyone help on this please.